# Ansible :: [WARNING]: Module did not set no_log for update_password

Tags: ansible, rabbitmq

I am trying to create a RabbitMQ node using Terraform and Ansible scripts. Other scripts are executing successfully but I am facing a warning while running this script of adding a user on the RabbitMQ node.

```bash
[WARNING]: Module did not set no_log for update_password

failed: [rabbit-node1] (item=admin) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl -q -n rabbit list_users", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "configure_priv": ".*", 
            "force": false, 
            "node": "rabbit", 
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
            "permissions": [
                {
                    "configure_priv": ".*", 
                    "read_priv": ".*", 
                    "vhost": "/", 
                    "write_priv": ".*"
                }
            ], 
            "read_priv": ".*", 
            "state": "present", 
            "tags": "administrator,admin", 
            "update_password": "on_create", 
            "user": "admin", 
            "vhost": "/", 
            "write_priv": ".*"
        }
    }, 
    "item": "admin", 
    "msg": "Error:********@rabbit-node1.\n * Suggestion: start it with \"rabbitmqctl start_app\" and try again", 
    "rc": 70, 
    "stderr": "Error: rabbit application is not running on node rabbit@rabbit-node1.\n * Suggestion: start it with \"rabbitmqctl start_app\" and try again\n", 
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Error: rabbit application is not running on node rabbit@rabbit-node1.", 
        " * Suggestion: start it with \"rabbitmqctl start_app\" and try again"
    ], 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

The `main.yml` file for the user creation in Rabbitmq node contains the following:

```yaml
- name: add user
  rabbitmq_user:
    user: "{{ item }}"
    password: "{{ ADMIN_PASS }}"
    tags: administrator,{{item}}
    vhost: /
    configure_priv: .*
    write_priv: .*
    read_priv: .*
    state: present
  with_items:
  - admin
```

Comment: The warning is realted to 'update_password' field. Ansible is guessing that 'update_password' is sensitive information. The actual error is different (if you fix the actual error task might not fail and just display warning). The actual error you are facing as per your question is this: 

    "msg": "Error:********@rabbit-node1.\n * Suggestion: start it with \"rabbitmqctl start_app\" and try again", 
    "rc": 70, 
    "stderr": "Error: rabbit application is not running on node rabbit@rabbit-node1.\n * Suggestion: start it with \"rabbitmqctl start_app\" and try again\n",

Answer (score 6):

Change the code in the following way:

```yaml
- name: add user
  no_log: true
  rabbitmq_user:
    user: "{{ item }}"
    password: "{{ ADMIN_PASS }}"
    tags: administrator,{{item}}
    vhost: /
    configure_priv: .*
    write_priv: .*
    read_priv: .*
    state: present
  with_items:
  - admin
```

The key point is the `no_log: true` option.

Answer (score 3):

This is something in the source of the module. When you create a parameter in the source of the module that contains "password", but you don't set the option of "no_log=True", Ansible starts throwing this warning in the module. Here is an example that shows a module where that option is set. See the last line with the additional option in the definition.

```
def run_module():
# define available arguments/parameters a user can pass to the module
module_args = dict(
    soap_url=dict(type='str', required=True),
    request_username=dict(type='str', required=True),
    request_password=dict(type='str', required=True, no_log=True),
)
```

Comment: That's the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alex's answer is correct... but it doesn't parse.
I don't think it matters but I always put task controls on the bottom.

```
- name: add user
  rabbitmq_user:
    user: "{{ item }}"
    password: "{{ ADMIN_PASS }}"
    tags: administrator,{{item}}
    vhost: /
    configure_priv: .*
    write_priv: .*
    read_priv: .*
    state: present
  no_log: true
  with_items:
  - admin
```